# How can i apply custom condition on one-page checkout before grand Total?

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, shopping-cart-price-rules

Below is my code for getting checkout cart grand total weight,

```
<span class="label">
<?php echo $this->__('Cart Weight:') ?></span> 
<?php
    echo Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')
        ->getQuote()
        ->getShippingAddress()
        ->getWeight();
?>
```

-> `Output is grand total weight of checkout cart`. Here i need to apply my below condition,

eg: `If my checkout cart total weight is 5.000 means my packing charges will be apply.`

like, 
      (Consider my Cart Weight: 5.000)

```
Subtotal    68.80
Shipping & Handling (Flat Rate - Fixed) 15.00
Packing Charge : 75 (My required custom condition)
Grand Total 158.8
```

Note: I did grand total weight of checkout cart, how can i merge custom condition and packing charge.

I just leaner of PHP, lead me with your help.

```
Starting(KG)    End(KG) Packing Charges

0               5.000   75
5.001          10.000   120
10.001         15.000   170
15.001         20.000   220
20.001         25.000   270
25.001         30.000   320
30.001         35.000   370
35.001         40.000   420
40.001         45.000   470
45.001         50.000   520
50.001         55.000   570
55.001         60.000   620
60.001         65.000   670
65.001         70.000   720
70.001         75.000   770
75.001         80.000   820
80.001         85.000   870
85.001         90.000   920
90.001         95.000   970
95.001         100.000  1000
```

How can i do it by Shopping cart pricing rule, if any other options exits, welcome.

Comment: You can use webshopapps metrix rate also

Comment: Now i am using webshopapps metrix rate, for Shipping Cost display to customer,  i want to display separately packing charges to customer, if i wrong, pls correct me.

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala Is possible can i enter weight as KG in webshopapps metrix rate, because Default UPS, FEDEX, DHL required products weight as KG, but i am using Grams for webshopapps metrix rate. Is possible can i use products weight as KG in webshopapps metrix rate.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend to just use the Magento TableRates based on Cart weight